Name nested column list with specific name
This is my code
library(tidyverse)

# Criar um dataframe de exemplo com dados de futebol
dat <- tibble(
  continent = rep(c("Asia", "Europe", "Africa", "Americas", "Oceania"), each = 5),
  number_of_teams = sample(25:30, 25, replace = TRUE),
  country = c("Japan", "South Korea", "China", "Iran", "Australia", 
              "Germany", "France", "Spain", "Italy", "England",
              "Nigeria", "Egypt", "South Africa", "Ghana", "Cameroon",
              "Brazil", "Argentina", "USA", "Mexico", "Colombia",
              "New Zealand", "Fiji", "Solomon Islands", "Tahiti", "Papua New Guinea"),
  games = sample(25:30, 25, replace = TRUE),
  goals_team = sample(15:30, 25, replace = TRUE),
  team_value = sample(1:10, 25, replace = TRUE)
)

# Aninhar (nest) os dados por continente
nested_data <- dat %>%
  group_by(continent) %>%
  nest() %>%
  ungroup()

My problem is to name the column list
In other words when I do nested_data$data I would like to see the continents name on each element list
Is it possible to solve this using the nest() function?

Not sure, but you can add another line: %>% mutate(data=setNames(data, continent)). And you can shorten your code to: nested_data <- dat %>% nest(.by=continent)

@Edward I thought that the elements name could be set using the nestefucntion

Try cbind(unique(dat[1]), list2DF(list(data=split(dat, dat[1])))).

You can do something like this to add the column in with mutate
library(tidyverse)


nested_data <- dat %>%
  nest(.by = continent)  |> 
  mutate(data = map2(data, continent, \(datas, conts){
    datas |> 
      mutate(continent = conts)
  }))

nested_data$data[1]
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 5 × 6
#>   number_of_teams country     games goals_team team_value continent
#>             <int> <chr>       <int>      <int>      <int> <chr>    
#> 1              29 Japan          28         16         10 Asia     
#> 2              27 South Korea    28         18          1 Asia     
#> 3              27 China          27         17          4 Asia     
#> 4              25 Iran           25         17          1 Asia     
#> 5              25 Australia      25         17          9 Asia

Created on 2024-07-13 with reprex v2.1.0
